# when should i use my own defined webroot and server root

Tags: php

```
$thisFile = str_replace('\\', '/', __FILE__);
$docRoot = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];

$webRoot  = str_replace(array($docRoot, 'library/config.php'), '', $thisFile);
$srvRoot  = str_replace('library/config.php', '', $thisFile);
```

This is how I get the web root and the server root

*web root* is the folder name where my files belongs, *server root* is the `C:/xampp/htdocs/folder_name`

I just want to ask when should I use webroot and server root.

I just notice that if you are referencing a file ex: href or img src, then only web root works but not server root

But, if you require a file, ex. `require_once 'file.php';` only server root works not webroot

Comment: I think you are confusing the path on your server with the path in the URL.

Comment: Why don't you just use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/your/path/here"`

Comment: sir i didnt get it sir please explain

Comment: There's two "spaces" you have to consider when dealing with files on a web server. There's the "file system space", which is the view of your server when you're looking at it from a command prompt or via (say) Windows Explorer,e .g. `c:\foo\bar\baz.txt`. Then there's "web space", which is view of your server as provided by URLs, e.g `http://example.com/baz.txt`. Using webroots when dealing with filesystem operations usually won't work.

Comment: path in my server is server root right and web root is path in the url, but please read my question

Comment: @user1892732 see my answer below. I think this is what you're trying to do

Comment: @Marc B but why when i reference a file thru href and img src the web root didnt work

Comment: did you try entering those href/src urls into the browser address bar yourself and see if anything comes up? did you check the server's error log to see what it's really trying to access? an incorrect path will show up as a 404 error.

Comment: Wouldn't the `$webRoot` value just be `'/'` in your code?  Also wouldn't `$srvRoot` be equal to `$docRoot`?

Comment: now $srvRoot in my code is $docRoot + the folder where my files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are confusing the server path with the URL path.

On your server, the files are stored at `C:/xampp/htdocs/folder_name`, but according to your web browser, they are at `http://localhost/folder_name`.  When your browser loads the files, it doesn't know they are in `C:/xampp/htdocs/`.

NOTE: *None of the code you have there will get you the "web root".*

`__FILE__` will return the path of the file on your *server*, like: `` `C:/xampp/htdocs/include/header.php ``.

`$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` will return you the path on the *server* where the files are, like: `C:/xampp/htdocs/`.

To get your "web root", you need to use `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']`.  This will return you `example.com` (or whatever).  You're probably gonna need to append `http(s)://` to it.

```
$serverRoot = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$webRoot = ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] ? 'https://' : 'http://') . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
```

You can also just use `/` as your web root.

```
<img src='http://example.com/images/wall.png" />
```

and

```
<img src='/images/wall.png" />
```

should be equivalent.

Try to `var_dump($_SERVER);`, it'll give you some fun information.

**EDIT**: Use [`dirname`](http://php.net/dirname) if you want to get the "sub folder" under the "root folder".  The above will give you the main root.

```
$serverPath = dirname(__FILE__); // or __DIR__
$webPath = dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
```

Comment: why should i get rid of str replace?

Comment: @user1892732: Why do you think you need it?  The `$_SERVER` array contains all the strings you need, no need to manually parse `__FILE__`.

Comment: but $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] didnt have the folder where my file belongs

Comment: @user1892732: That wouldn't be the "root" folder.  That would just be a sub-folder.  Have a look at `var_dump($_SERVER);`, it's got a lot of fun stuff.

Comment: <img src='http://example.com/images/wall.png" /> <--- why when i use the server root path here i didnt work

Comment: @user1892732: To get the sub-folder (not the "root" folder), try `__DIR__` or `$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]`.

Comment: @user1892732: The web browser has no clue about your server!  The browser doesn't know what `C:/xampp/htdocs/` is.  Your server root is where the files are on your server.

Comment: so I can only reference a file if its inside my webroot?

Comment: @user1892732: Yep!  The "web root" is where the browser is looking :-)

Comment: ok that makes sense so if the server host 2 different sites other site can't reference a file of other site

Answer (score 1):

I think you're over-complicating things. You can build the path like this:

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/your/path/here"
```

So, if you're adding a `require_once` do this at the top of your script:

```
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/your/path/here.php")
```

When referencing an image you can do this:

```
<img src="/my/path/image.jpg" alt="" />
```

The`/` brings it back to the root and builds the path from there.

Comment: but how about when I reference a file thru href and img src web root didnt work so that also will not work

Comment: sir please answer my question about web root

Comment: <img src="/my/path/image.jpg" alt="" /> <--- why when i use the server root path here i didnt work